# how to explode date from this format by regex?

Tags: php, laravel, regex-negation

I have some entities such as:

> یکشبه، 20 فروردین (از 390000 تومان)

I want to have the "20 فروردین" at first, then separate them into '20' and 'فروردین'.how to do such thing.
speciallym I am wondering for the regex I must use in PHP for the first level.
thanks.

Comment: test explode(' ',$str);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = ' یکشبه، 20 فروردین (از 390000 تومان)';
$str = explode(' ',$str);
$date  = $str[1].$str[2];
$price = $str[5];
```

Use explode if this string not very complex!

Comment: alan bad moghast vagrna in soal bi keifiat koli down vote mikhord!!! khajesh mikkona ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have a new Idea after reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php#111307) and wrote this pieces of code:

```
<php
    function multiexplode ($delimiters,$string) {
    $ready = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $string);
    $launch = explode($delimiters[0], $ready);
    return  $launch;
}


$mytext = " یکشبه، 20 فروردین (از 390000 تومان)";
$myexploded = multiexplode(array("،","("),$mytext);
print_r($myexploded);



?>
```